# Split char* into two char* according to delimiter

Tags: c, string, char

I need to split a full path to a file into two `char*`, using a `\` delimiter.

For example:

```
c:\temp\file.dll
```

should be parsed into to these two `char*`:

```
1) c:\temp\

2) file.dll
```

I thought about using `strtok` but is there any simpler way to do that without using tokens and re-assembling the `char*` after the split (which `strtok` will do).

This should work on windows.

Cheers.

Comment: Are you deliberately confusing `/` and `\ `?

Comment: No, it's a mistake. will edit. EDITED :)

Comment: Even on windows it's a good idea to allow `'/'` as path separator.

Comment: I always find this extremely disturbing. Programming a computer requires attention to detail, and if you can't even keep two characters apart mentally, how will you ever muster the attention span to solve anything non-trivial? (In C\C++, perhaps.)

Comment: For MSVC, you can use [splitpath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e737s6tf.aspx)

Comment: what about navigate the string right to left and split at the first slash?

Comment: @WileTheCoyot It may give incorrect result for utf-8 and multi-byte strings.

Comment: @MohitJain: I'd like you to explain how, utf-8 being self-synchronizing I don't see any way an ASCII character like `'/'` could accidentally match part of a multi-byte character.

Comment: @MatthieuM. OK not `'/'`, but as OP asked for `'\'` (ascii code `0x5C`) which may get mathed with 100s of character for ex in [shift jis encoding](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.sjis.shtml) One such example is uwasa(噂). So one should scan string from left to right ignoring extended characters and never right to left.

Comment: @MohitJain: Ah, but then this is no longer utf-8 (or even utf-16). Yes of course there are encoding that are "tricky", but there is no good reason to use them (internally). In the absence of precision regarding the encoding, I'd rather assume the OP uses a well-behaved encoding (such as utf-8) rather than a "weird" one; there can be as many encodings as the human mind can conceive after all.

Comment: I agree with you MatthieuM but it is not always you who decides the encoding. I lived in Japan for years, and JIS/ShiftJIS was the encoding most of the legacy modules used. I tried to isolate my work as much as possible from that by creating required adapters, but learned to keep in mind that my string solutions work for such encodings.

Answer (score 1):

Do a search from the end, that should work:

```
char* findlastof(char* s, char* delim) {
    char* r;
    for(r=s; *s; s++)
        for(char* x = delim;*x;x++)
            if(*s==*x) {
                r = s;
                break;
            }
    return s;
}
```

Feed it your path separators and you'll get the basename.
Getting the path left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It may give incorrect result for utf-8 and multi-byte strings

Comment: @MohitJain: No, the result will be right for UTF-8 and other extended ASCII mbcs, as there's no system using non-ASCII path separators.

Comment: I agree path separator is ascii even in multibyte string environment. But second byte of some multi-byte characters may match path separator `'\'` (ascii code `0x5C`) in OP's environment. There are many such characters available in [shift jis](http://www.rikai.com/library/kanjitables/kanji_codes.sjis.shtml)

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to [`boost::string_ref`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html), then it's already done.

```
std::pair<boost::string_ref, boost::string_ref> split(boost::string_ref path) {
    size_t const lastSlash = path.rfind('/');
    return std::make_pair(path.substr(0, lastSlash+1), path.substr(lastSlash+1));
}
```

If you do not, I urge you to re-create this class (you can inspire yourself greatly from the Boost Header because of its liberal license) because it really makes this kind of jobs so easy.

Comment: As far as I can see this answer correctly solves the problem, whilst being safe and using a feature that is ongoing standardization so that it will sooner or later be part of everyone's Standard library. And yet, apparently, it's either incomplete or incorrect (or the downvoter just made a mistake, which is hard to know since no reason was stated), so if someone was so kind as to point out what it's missing that would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but looking at the question the OP uses Windows-only paths. Looks like everyone who got an upvote (not Dieter) also got a downvote (dito). That's egalitarian...

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in a comment, use splitpath.

Use the safe version though, [splitpath_s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8e46eyt7.aspx)

Comment: You could add code to support your answer, this is not much better than a comment with a link

Comment: @EdChum criticism accepted, but I assumed this is trivial.

Comment: Doesn't this split it a bit too much?

Comment: @Bgie: It is and it is not; for example a recommendation on the number of characters to reserve for the various parts would be welcome (that's the trouble with such a low-level type as `char*`, and why no one should use it as an output...)

Answer (score 0):

Even without using dedicated functions such as Windows' `_splitpath`, it is embarrasingly easy using standard string functions only.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (void)
{
    char *fullpath = "c:\\temp\\file.dll";
    char *ptr, *pathname, *filename;

    ptr = strrchr (fullpath, '\\');
    if (ptr == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    filename = strdup (ptr+1);
    if (filename == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    pathname = malloc((size_t)(ptr-fullpath+2));
    if (pathname == NULL)
        return EXIT_FAILURE;

    pathname[ptr-fullpath+1] = 0;
    strncpy (pathname, fullpath, (size_t)(ptr-fullpath+1));

    printf ("pathname [%s]\n", pathname);
    printf ("filename [%s]\n", filename);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

```
pathname [c:\temp\]
filename [file.dll]
```

Comment: I'd add a test for `strrchr()` having returned `NULL`.

Comment: True; making it (more) bomb-proof by adding that requires NULL checks for the explicit and implict `malloc` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might utilize boost::filesystem:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    //boost::filesystem::path path("c:\\temp\\file.dll");
    boost::filesystem::path path("c:/temp/file.dll");
    std::cout << path.parent_path() << ", " << path.filename() << '\n';
}
```

Which gives:

```
"c:/temp", "file.dll"
```

(on my linux system)

Answer (score -1):

If the original string can be modified:

```
char *fullpath = "c:\\temp\\file.dll";

char *p = strrchr(fullpath, '\\');
if(p) {
  *p = '\0';
  char *filename = p+1;
  char *pathname = fullpath;
  // ...
}
```

The path will not be \ terminated though.